# java, getting the highest value from multiple arrays

Tags: java, arrays, comparison

```
int[] player1,player2,player3,player4;
int[] player1 =new int[12];
int[] player2 =new int[12];
int[] player3 =new int[12];
int[] player4 =new int[12];
```

Each player has 13 random numbers inside.
Is there a way to compare player1[i] with players2,3,4[i] to find the highest value?
The player with the highest value will win that round.

```
int score = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < player1[i]; i++){
    if (player[i] > score)
    score = player[i];
}
```

This is the code I've made, but it can only compare one player with a score.

Comment: So, what is the actual question here ? Did you write any code towards the solution ?

Comment: 'code' int score = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < player1[i]; i++){
 if (player[i] > score)
 score = player[i];
}

this is the code ive made but it can only compare one player with a score

Comment: please, edit the question as writing code in comments is totally unreadable

Comment: Each player can't have 13 random numbers, since the array length is 12. And your loop is wrong: `i < player1[i]` doesn't make sense. You want i to go from 0 to the length of the array (not included)

Comment: but position 0 would be the first value?

Comment: @Nafroman With a length of 12 you can only have 12 not 13 values.

Comment: An array of length 12 have indices going from 0 to 11 inclusive.

Comment: ahhhh that could be where im messing up, i thought it would cover 0 to 12 inclusive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it like this

```
public static int max(int... nums) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i: nums) if(max < i) max = i;
    return max;
}

int[] player1,player2,player3,player4;
....
int allMax = max(max(player1), max(player2), max(player3), max(player4));
```

i.e. the max of all, is the max of the individual maximums.

Comment: @JBNizet Well spotted, much cleaner.